# SoundCloud API: GET succeeds, HEAD fails

Tags: http, soundcloud

I use the SoundCloud API to retrieve the stream URL for a streamable track.
I follow the redirect and I end up with an URL that looks like:

```
http://ec-media.soundcloud.com/eodihgiuh.128.mp3?<a string>
    AWSAccessKeyId=<access key>
    &Expires=<timestamp>
    &Signature=<signature>
```

or

```
http://ak-media.soundcloud.com/euieuieie.128.mp3?
    AWSAccessKeyId=<access key>
    &Expires=<timestamp>
    &Signature=<signature>
    &__gda__=<a string>
```

Then I start streaming the MP3 data at this URL.

First I send a `HEAD` request to read the `Content-Length` header, so that I know how many `GET` requests I will have to send in order to play the whole song.

Then I send several partial `GET` requests, each one with a different `Range` header.

The problem is that sometimes the `HEAD` request returns a `403` status code, even though a `GET` request to the exact same URL returns with a `200` status code. It seems that this happens if and only if the host is `ak-media.soundcloud.com`.

Is this supposed to happen? I expected the `HEAD` request to return exactly the same headers as the `GET` request, only without the body response.

Cheers,

PB

P.S: I should probably mention that my code is *not* running on a computer, but on an audio device with a tiny 8-bit processor which has *extremely* limited resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, currently we only offer guaranteed proper response for GET requests.

As a hack, you could try to do requests with very short `range`s.

Comment: Thanks, 
Actually I implemented this workaround while waiting for an answer :D